# When sizing up a circle(with postition relative) using js, scroll bars appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this color theme change animations that are basically a circle that gets bigger fast with a color depending on which button you press.

My Problem is, that at the end of the animation the circle get's so wide and high, that the page size increases even though the circle position is set to absolute. I would like the page to stay the same size without beeing affected by the size of the circle.

Also if anyone has possible improvements to share let me know!

```js
function ultraDarkMode(){
  grow(0,0,0);
}

function whiteMode(){
  grow(255,255,255);
}

function darkMode(){
  grow(68,58,58);
}

function grow(r,g,b){
  let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  let body = document.body;
  circle.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  circle.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 50px 100px rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  let i = 1;
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    circle.style.height = circle.clientHeight + 100 + "px";
    circle.style.width = circle.clientWidth + 100 + "px";
    if(i == 30) {
      circle.style.height = 150 + "px";
      circle.style.width = 150 + "px";
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;
  }, 15)
}
```

```css
#circle{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 100px darkgray;
  z-index: -1;
/*  offset x offset y blur radius spread radius und color  */
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick=darkMode()>Darkmode</button>
<button type="button" onclick=whiteMode()>WhiteMode</button>
<button type="button" onclick=ultraDarkMode()>UltraDarkMode</button>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: try **CSS** `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Adding overflow hidden to the body worked! can you also post a answer so i can accept your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following CSS to your `#circle` selector and it prevented the scrollbar from appearing.

```css
#circle{
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
//...
}
```

Applying **hidden overflow** on `body` seems to work but I don't know how that may affect your futur code.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It stops the animation for a short time which makes it look laggy

Comment: @0szi I observed that your circle grows horizontally faster than vertically.

Comment: that doesn't matter! : )

Comment: @0szi I mean that is the cause of what feels like a lag for the `max-` styling solution. Anyway good luck for the rest of your project.